# Google Youtube API

Tags: web-applications, youtube-api

Is there any restriction on the number of request that any web application can send to google using youttube api???I mean to say is it something like that any web application can send 10000 request per day to google server using google youtube api without authentication. But if any web application uses authentication method(auth 2.0) then there is no restriction on the number of request. You can send any number of request using authentication.can you pls clear my confusion?? it is very important for me as well as urgent also.

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ mentions the API limits: https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#limits

Basically, the limits are not fixed (and not public) but any of your API requests might return with `too_many_recent_calls`, and in that case you'll have to wait a few minutes before retrying.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.it cleared my doubts. And your link is also useful for me.

Answer (score -1):

i think youtube have a cota limit of 1000000 units per day
also each operation(simple search,upload video, watch video...) have the numbers of units

Comment: Could you add a source for this please?

Comment: for exemple A write operation has a cost of approximately 50 units.
A video upload has a cost of approximately 1600 units https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started